# Missing units (IcePack, Generics.Collections)

Tags: delphi

Hi where i can find these units: (IcePack, Generics.Collections)?
i have delphi 2006, i think Generics.Collection is only on delphi 2010/XE

Answer (score 4):

The Generics units were added in Delphi 2009 and could be of no use to you since your Delphi doesn't support generics.

IcePack is not part of Delphi and no doubt can be located with a web search.

Comment: Generics were introduced in Delphi 2009

Comment: ..although if you are interested in Generics, forget Delphi 2009, Generics are practically unusable. Much better in Delphi 2010 and XE.

Comment: @mjn thanks, now corrected. @l3m0n What was wrong with the answer at the [Emba Forums](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=341554&tstart=0)?