# What are some alternatives of Generics Collections TStack?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I want to store some string data into a **stack**.

The [Delphi Documentation for System.Generics.Collections.TStack](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Seattle/en/Generics_Collections_TStack_%28Delphi%29) is for Delphi XE4.

I read the answer of Mr. Heffernan in [Missing units (IcePack, Generics.Collections)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631270/missing-units-icepack-generics-collections)

What are some alternatives of **stack** aside from **arrays**?

Comment: Why are looking for an alternative? It is still available in XE8 (also in D 10 Seattle). That the example code is labelled XE4 just means that that was the last time it has been edited, it is still valid. The discussion you then linked to, was regarding somebody with D2006 asking for TStack, which was published in D2009 and therefore not suitable to him.

Comment: I tried to add **System.Generics** into the _uses list_ of my code. But it says that:

[dcc32 Fatal Error] frmMain.pas(12): F2613 Unit 'System.Generics' not found.

Comment: You need to add `System.Generics.Collections`

Comment: @MBo, that doesn't work.

Comment: It does - unless you have done something strange. Please post code (edit your question) that fails. If possible, reduce it to a simple, stand-alone console application. You may discover, during your simplification, what the problem is...

Comment: @Wennie: it should work. If not, probably something is wrong with the library path of your project. Make sure it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are trying to use non-generic stack (that lives in `System.Contnrs`).
Here is full working example for generic `TStack<>`:

```
program ProjectC;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Generics.Collections;

var
  Stack: TStack<Integer>;

begin
  Stack := TStack<Integer>.Create;
  try
    Stack.Push(1);
    Stack.Push(2);
    while Stack.Count > 0 do
      Writeln(Stack.Pop);
  finally
    Stack.Free;
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```